# Scala sbt jar allows import when class path is passed on command line, but not in REPL

Tags: scala, sbt

I've built a small test jar with Scala and SBT.  If I put the classpath argument on the Scala REPL command line, it imports the package perfectly.  However if I get into the shell and then add the classpath, it does not recognize the import.  Being new to Scala this confuses me so I hope someone can explain.  I'll try to provide enough information without going overboard.

```
scala -cp configparser_2.10-1.0.jar 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_75).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import com.oaktreepeak.util._
import com.oaktreepeak.util._

scala> val c = new OakConfig()
c: com.oaktreepeak.util.OakConfig = com.oaktreepeak.util.OakConfig@58d9a418
```

Now I'll wait and load the classpath to the jar after I'm in the shell:

```
scala 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_75).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :cp configparser_2.10-1.0.jar
Added '/home/*****/Dyn/projects/DynECT2/scala/common/ConfigParser/test-configs/configparser_2.10-1.0.jar'.  Your new classpath is:
".:/home/*****/Dyn/projects/DynECT2/scala/common/ConfigParser/test-configs/configparser_2.10-1.0.jar"
Nothing to replay.

scala> import com.oaktreepeak.util._
<console>:7: error: object oaktreepeak is not a member of package com
   import com.oaktreepeak.util._
              ^

scala>
```

Here is my build.sbt file:

```
name := "ConfigParser"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

organization := "com.oaktreepeak"
```

And the single Scala source file:

```
package com.oaktreepeak.util

import scala.io._
import scala.util.parsing.json._

class OakConfig {
    var iRollupAfter: Int = -1;
    def Load(sPath: String) {
        val config = Source.fromFile(sPath).mkString
        val json:Option[Any] =JSON.parseFull(config)
        val map:Map[String,Any] = json.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
        iRollupAfter = map.get("RollupAfter").get.asInstanceOf[Double].toInt
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas or explanations?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:cp` was broken in Scala 2.10, and has been replaced with (a working) `:require` in Scala 2.11.

If you're new to Scala I would recommend using the latest, stable version of Scala, which currently is 2.11.6.

Also, as you're new to Scala, if you want to try things out from your project in the REPL (which is a great workflow) from sbt just run `console`, which will compile your code and give you REPL with all of Scala's classes, your projects classes and the classes for all your dependencies! No need to feed manually feed the REPL a classpath.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that it's a bug.  I actually thought that I was doing something wrong.  I'm perfectly content to specify jars on the command line; but I couldn't just let it slide ;-)

Comment: nice.  :cp has been broken since approximately  forever.  why did  they neither fix nor alias :cp and instead make a new command?

Comment: Seems because ":require is more limited, but less broken", and probably quite a re-write, but still some kind of info from running ":cp" could've helped: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6502?focusedCommentId=71186&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-71186

Comment: Comment on the command name at https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4051 so I guess it was my idea. There's a SO question asking how would you implement require, and this was the mechanism. It's also worth noting that "class path" is itself a limited and broken concept. And it's true that those repl commands come and go.